# Can I create a new Azure ML-workspace when creating an ACI from cloud shell

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry, azure-machine-learning-service

How can I create a new Azure Machine Learning workspace when creating a new Azure Container Instance from Azure cloud shell.

Here is a sample of the command am using to create the ACI.

`az container create --name dev-container –resource-group XXX –location eastus –image mcr.microsoft.com/XXX –cpu 2 –memory 6 –environment-variables WORKSPACE_NAME=XXX`

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me more about the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the problem from the opposite direction than the Azure ML PG. My understanding is that when you make an Azure ML workspace, an Azure Container Instance service is automatically spun up and is inherently tied to the Azure ML workspace. [Check out a similar question](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1049) another user had this week

More generally, Azure ML has a core feature called `Environments` which provides a simple interface for creating custom Docker/Conda environments.